# Creating an object in inherited class sets attribute from superclass null in database java

Tags: java, database, inheritance, null

For a school project I have to make a library system with different items like books, dvds, cds,... So I decided to make an superclass Item with the reoccuring attributes that each item has. The attribute names are in Dutch(name, theme,available,...) but you should get the general idea

```
    package domein;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
    import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;


    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @NamedQueries({
      @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i"),
      @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findAllBeschikbaar", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.beschikbaar = 1")
    })
    public abstract class Item implements Serializable
    {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private int id;
       private String naam;
       private String uitgever;

       @Column(length = 1024)
       private String beschrijving;
       private String leeftijd;
       private String thema;
       private boolean beschikbaar;



       public Item(){};

       public Item(String naam, String uitgever, String beschrijving, String thema,String leeftijd)
{

    this.uitgever = uitgever;
    this.beschrijving = beschrijving;
    this.thema = thema;
    this.leeftijd = leeftijd;
    beschikbaar = true;
};

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNaam() {
    return naam;
}

public void setNaam(String naam) {
    this.naam = naam;
}

public String getUitgever() {
    return uitgever;
}

public void setUitgever(String uitgever) {
    this.uitgever = uitgever;
}

public String getBeschrijving() {
    return beschrijving;
}

public void setBeschrijving(String beschrijving) {
    this.beschrijving = beschrijving;
}

public String getLeeftijd() {
    return leeftijd;
}

public void setLeeftijd(String leeftijd) {
    this.leeftijd = leeftijd;
}

public String getThema() {
    return thema;
}

public void setThemas(String thema) {
    this.thema = thema;
}

public boolean isBeschikbaar() {
    return beschikbaar;
}

public void setBeschikbaar(boolean beschikbaar) {
    this.beschikbaar = beschikbaar;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNaam();
}


}
```

Now for example of a subclass, this is the class book

```
    package domein;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

    @Entity
    @NamedQuery(name = "findAllBoeken", query = "SELECT b FROM Boek b")
    public class Boek extends Item implements Serializable
{
private String auteur;

protected Boek() 
{
    super();
}

public Boek(String auteur, String naam, String uitgever, String beschrijving, String thema,String leeftijd) 
{
    super(naam, uitgever, beschrijving, thema, leeftijd);
    this.auteur = auteur;
}


public String getAuteur() {
    return auteur;
}

public void setAuteur(String auteur) {
    this.auteur = auteur;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.getNaam() + " - " + getAuteur();
}

}
```

The problem that I am having is the following. When creating an new book in the gui of my program there are no errors, the system is set to return: "Book: " + txtTitel.getText() + "succesfully added."

```
  private void addBoek()
{
    ItemRepository repository = new ItemRepository();
    repository.create(new Boek(txtAuteur.getText(),txtTitel.getText(),txtUitgeverij.getText(), txtBeschrijving.getText(),txtThema.getText() ,txtLeeftijd.getText()));
     Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
     alert.setTitle("Boek toegevoegd");
     alert.setHeaderText(null);
     alert.setContentText("Het boek: " + txtTitel.getText() + " is toegevoegd aan de databank en kan nu worden uitgeleend.");
     alert.showAndWait();

}
```

But when i go into the database in the Items tabel all the fields have the correct values except for the Name/Title which has value . This is rather annoying since the page where u can search if the item is available shows a list  entirely filled with Book: null by author x or DVD: null from Spielberg

All help is welcome , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor **I think** you forgot to initialize the name :

```
public Item(String naam, String uitgever, String beschrijving, String thema,String leeftijd)
     {

     this.uitgever = uitgever;
     this.beschrijving = beschrijving;
     this.thema = thema;
     this.leeftijd = leeftijd;
     beschikbaar = true;
     this.naam = naam; // HERE
 };
```

Comment: Wow, you were right. These stupid mistakes almost made me go crazy >:( Thank you =D